# I want to Change the Direction of Text in Arabic From Right to Left

Tags: css, text, translation, arabic, direction

Anybody can help me out? I am using webflow for one of my client. The Website uses Weglot to translate text from arabic. The problem I am facing is the text direction issue. When a Plugin translates the text from English to arabic, It does not change the direction that should be from right to left for arabic.

I checked the Inspector element and found the problem. The style should be inherited from Body tag which is not happening. Can anybody know to fix this?

I want to change the text direction in arabic. The plugin uses `html[lang="ar"]` to make changes in arabic.

Images:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Please share the relevant (*minimal*) code in your question in order that we can reproduce the problem, *pictures* of code are of no use whatsoever, are actively inaccessible, and serve to impede those trying to help (nobody wants to transcribe code from an image). Please, see the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to go is to **not define any default text alignment at all** as HTML automatically adjusts the document default alignment based on the `direction` property and/or `dir` attribute. This automatically means that when the `text-align` property gets specifically defined in CSS, its inverse behavior will have to be defined as well.

Simple rule of thumb: don't define any text alignment and search for exceptions to correct as not all HTML tags behave as expected.

However, with `<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">` you can test for the `[dir]` attribute in CSS, like

```css
html[dir="ltr"] .body-display { text-align: left  }
html[dir="rtl"] .body-display { text-align: right }
```

Alternatively, for on-the-fly use throughout the document:

```css
[dir="ltr"] { text-align: left  }
[dir="rtl"] { text-align: right }
```

Specific cases requiring manual definition of text alignment will require manual testing for [lang] and/or [dir].

MDN reference: '[dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir)' attribute.